# What are the advantages of building CSS codes out of dual-containing classical codes?

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

Is there any advantage to building CSS codes out of dual-containing classical codes, as opposed to general CSS codes? Other than satisfying the commutation conditions directly, are there any useful properties that the dual-containing codes have that general codes do not?

Comment: Can you define dual-containing classical codes? If you mean CSS codes such as the Steane code, an advantage is that they have a transversal Hadamard gate.